# Ping level in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends, moba

Different types of games have different requirement to the ping. I am new to MOBA and interested in its ping requirements. Particularly of ping requirements of League of Legends.

1. What is the maximum acceptable ping level for comfort playing in League of Legends?
2. What ping level is generally considered good in League of Legends?
3. What is the level of the ping in League of Legends than less then that value does not grants any advantage?

Comment: League does have it's own 'rating' for ping, giving it a color to match how good or bad your ping is. Green is best, ~1-150 ms. Yellow is ok, orange is bad, red is going to be pretty much unplayable 500+ ms. You can view your ping in-game by pressing shift+f

Comment: @Katustrawfic Ctrl+F for displaying ping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I knew some picture existed, the win rate versus ping. It is 6 months old and there are 3403014 games used for the statistics, so it's a fairly good representative.

- 1 and 2 of your questions are opinion based, so I will not answer them here (but you can draw conclusions from the picture. For example a ping >100ms is bad).
- 3 however is a different story. You see that a ping lower then 50 ms results (well, you have to do it yourself of course) in a >50% win rate, which I call an advantage. So maybe you can say that 50ms is the threshold, and everything above that does not grant an advantage.

[image: Win rate vs Ping]

[source](http://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/1t23a0/latency_lag_vs_win_rate_in_league_of_legends_oc/) of the picture, for completeness and shizzle.

Comment: The fact that the sample size for games <50ms ping makes the confidence for high win rates at lower pings a little low. The win rate at those pings is probably higher because players who do well at the game work hard to keep their ping <50ms, *especially* pros. Great info though!

Comment: True. I was about to add a note with something like: Pro's also invest in optimization. Cables instead of Wifi for example, and a tip-top router. But I didn't got it formulated right. So ping doesn't determine your win-rate, but it helps :)

Comment: I run an Ethernet cable to my computer and a cable costs at most $10, that much everyone should do if they can :)

Comment: Sometimes it isn't possible, in a house with multiple floors for example. How much difference would a cheap-ass and a $150 make?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very interesting study. As I see on the graph, 20ms gives better win rate. Also 20ms is threshold, and if you have less then 20 you will not get more advantage. But I think that we need more sample size to definitely say, are all 20ms players pro or not.

Comment: @Mathias711 That's why I said if they can, I know with multiple floors running an Ethernet cable might not be possible. It depends on your router otherwise, it's worth measuring which percentage of packets are dropped between your computer and the router.

Comment: Although some information can be gained from these graphs, you can't make the kind of conclusions mentioned in this answer. This is because of the elo system. If you play consistently, and always have about the same ping, you'll end up winning 50% of the games since you'll meet evenly matched teams. This is regardless of if your ping is 20 or 200. My guess is that the win rate is higher for low pings since lots of players don't always have the same ping, so the only conclusion I'd dare to make is that if you have unusually low ping compared to what you're used to, you're more likely to win.